# Marginalization of intermediate variables $p(w|z, y) = \int_z p(w| x, z)p(z| x, y)dz$

Tags: probability, bayesian, marginal-distribution

I want to know if my statement and derivation of the marginalization of the "intermediate" variable is correct. The statement is as follows:

> Suppose a probabilistic factorization model $p(x, y, z, w) = p(x)p(y)p(w|x, y)p(z|x,y)$
> . Then the following relation holds: $p(w|z, y) = \int_z p(w| x, z)p(z| x, y)dz$.

The derivation of the above statement is as follows. Thanks to the factorization model we have $$p(z, w|x, y) = \frac{p(z, w, x, y)}{p(x, y)} = \frac{p(x)p(y)p(w|x, y)p(z|x, y)}{p(x)p(y)}=p(w|x, y)p(z|x, y).$$
Therefore, due to the sum rule we have
$$ p(w|z, y) = \int_z p(z, w| x, y)dz = \int_z p(w| x, z)p(z| x, y)dz.$$

Comment: Perhaps you are right, but I don't understand the last row of your reasoning. I don't really understand (or know) this “sum rule”. And how do you know $X$ and $Y$ are independent? You say $p_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=p_{X}\left(x\right)\cdot p_{Y}\left(y\right)$. Is it true, because the model says $p\left(x,y,z,w\right)=p\left(x\right)\cdot p\left(y\right)\cdot\ldots$? Does this model imply independence between the $X$ and $Y$ marginals?

Comment: @KapesMate Thanks for the commnet. I mean sum rule by marginalization, like in this case integrating $z$ out. And yest, the factorization model implies $p(x)$ and $p(y)$ are independent.